# Link of react-router-dom is not working in firefox

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have the following code in my `routes.js` file

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom'
import Home from './components/home/Home.jsx'
import Dashboard from './components/dashboard/Dashboard.jsx'
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router'

class Routes extends Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <Router history={browserHistory}>
        <div>
          <Switch>
            <Route path='/home' component={() => (<Home />)} />
            <Route path='/dashboard' component={() => (<Dashboard />)} />
            <Redirect to={{pathname: '/home'}} />
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </Router>
    )
  }
}

export default Routes
```

And following is my `Home.jsx`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom'

class Home extends Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>This is a home page.</h1>
        <button>
          <Link to='/dashboard'>Click here (Dashboard)</Link>
        </button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Home
```

But if i'm clicking on the button present in `Home.jsx` then it's working fine in chrome and safari and redirecting me to the `Dashboard` page but it's(this button in ``Home.jsx`) not responding in firefox. And i'm not getting it get stuck in firefox? So can anyone please help me in this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can just write `<Route path='/home' component={Home} />`. No need for the extra inline function. Does it work if you change to that and temporarily remove the `button` around the `Link`?

Comment: Yes without button it's working fine for me. But inside the button it's not working. I just tried it. It means it is not the problem with routing. It's is the problem with button click event. Is there any way to call the `<Link />` manually.

Comment: Manually i mean can i invoke the Link by writing it inside some function and call that function on click event of button?

Comment: Btw Thank you so much @Tholle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem and found out that you make it work in Firefox by nesting `<button>` inside a `<Link>`:

```js
class Home extends Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>This is a home page.</h1>
        <Link to="/dashboard">
          <button>
            Click here (Dashboard)
          </button>
        </Link>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of putting a `Link` inside a `button`, you can change the url programmatically by using the `history` prop that is passed to a component given to a `Route`.

```
class Home extends Component {
  handleClick = () => {
    this.props.history.push('/dashboard');
  };

  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>This is a home page.</h1>
        <button onClick={this.handleClick}>
          Click here (Dashboard)
        </button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

To make sure the `Home` component is given the [route props](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/api/Route/route-props), you must use the component directly in the `Route`'s `component` prop.

```
<Route path='/home' component={Home} />
```

Comment: if i'm doing that it's throwing the following errors while loading the home page itself

```
 [Show/hide message details.] Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.

Check the render method of `Route`.
```

Comment: @ShravanJain That's frustrating. [That's how you're supposed to use it](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/api/Route).

Comment: Awesome it worked for me. Thank you very very much. You made my day.